# post contact for specific rent in rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am developing a rental application to get practice into rest framework. There is a feature where buyer can contact rent owner by clicking contact button on the rent where he has to then fill his/her email_id etc. I know if i want to contact specific rent then i have to do something like this

```
rent = Rental.objects.get(id=token)
contact.objects.create(rent=rent, email_id=email_id, buyer=request.user)
```

I am confuse in rest framework create function of serializer and post function of APIView. Can anyone enlighten me with my example?

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)


class Contact(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rental = models.ForeignKey(Rental, related_name="rent")
    email_id = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)

class RentalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    galleries = GallerySerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Rental
        fields = ('__all__')

class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # buyer = UserSerializer(many=True)
    # rent = RentalSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'

class ContactedRent(APIView):
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    def get(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        """
        Returns a list of contactedRent
        """
        reply = {}
        try:
            contacted_rent = Contact.objects.filter(buyer_id=request.user.id)
            if token:
                specific_contacted_rent = contacted_rent.get(rental__id=token)
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(specific_contacted_rent).data
            else:
                print ('no token')
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(contacted_rent, many=True).data
        except Contact.DoesNotExist:
            return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()
        except:
            return error.UnknownError().as_response()
        else:
            return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        """
        create a new contact to the rent
        """
        rent = None
        if not token is None:
            try:
                # contact = Contact.objects.get(buyer_id=request.user.id, rental__id=token)
                rent = Rental.objects.get(id=token)
            except Rental.DoesNotExist:
                return RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()
            except:
                return UnknownError.as_response()
        serialized_data = self.serializer_class(instance=rent, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serialized_data.is_valid():
            serialized_data.save()
        else:
            return error.ValidationError(serialized_data.errors).as_response()
```

Please anyone help me to understand the create and post function of APIView with my example.

**UPDATE**

```
url(r'^contact/(?P<token>[0-9a-z]+)/$', ContactedRent.as_view(), name="create-contact-to-rent"),
```

Here token is the id of the rent that is going to be contacted by giving buyer information(email_id)

Comment: What is your urlconf like for `ContactedRent` `APIView`?  And what data are you passing to it?

Comment: updated my url. To contact rent, a rent id is needed so we can track which rent is contacted and send the contact information to that rent owner. It is similar to comment to a specific post.

Comment: So you no longer pass the `rental` ID in the POSTed data?  Since it's already in the URL?

Comment: Am i doing the wrong way?

Comment: Not really.  I just want to figure out what you really want.

Comment: I posted an answer anyway, assuming you don't want `rental` in your serializer.  There are many ways to do it, depending on how you want your API.  Also, there are many more view classes in `rest_framework` that you can use so you don't have to code things yourself, namely the `GenericAPIView`s and the `ViewSet`s.  Check their implementation at least to see how it could work for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want `rental` passed as submitted data, you might want to remove it from your serializer.

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['buyer', 'email_id']  # omit `rental` field
```

The `partial` argument to the serializer is for `PATCH` requests, when you only want to validate the submitted fields, *and* update only those fields.  (I feel that you're passing `partial=True` as a workaround because your serializer doesn't validate if you don't pass `rental`.)

Once you've removed `rental` from your serializer, you should now be able to do:

```
serialized_data = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
```

which should validate, given you passed a valid `buyer` and `email_id` values.  Then, when you call `save`, you pass the `rental` instance

```
serialized_data.save(rental=rent)
```

Comment: Would not there be use of create function? I am still confuse with create and post function?

Comment: Since you used a `ModelSerializer`, it can take care of doing the `Model.objects.create` for you.  Check `ModelSerializer.save` method's implementation to learn how it uses the `create` method, in case you really want to do the call yourself.

Comment: Can you just explain me the case of sending rental data vs the one you have done? Sorry for asking more. I am feeling difficult to understand the other way so i am learning from you by asking.

Comment: If the endpoint for adding a contact for Rental with ID 15 is `/contact/15/` and you require a POST data of `{"rental": 15, "buyer": 1, "email_id": "email@example.com"}`, then `rental` is redundant because it's in the URL as well as the data.  Also, what if in the URL the value is 14 and in the data it's 15?  Which one will you honor?  It's ambiguous in that case so it's better if `rental` is coming from either the URL or data but not both.

Comment: which one do you think the best way? passing from the url or the data? can you post this useful comment on the answer as well ? I am marking this as solved and also informative.

Comment: Personally, from what I can gather from your models, seeing that `Contact` has a `ForeignKey` to `Rental` and it looks like a `Contact` cannot stand on its own, i.e. it's a "weak entity" dependent on a `Rental`, I would nest it under my "rentals" resource, so, yeah, I would prefer the `Rental` to be identified from the URL and not via data. My URL structure would be `/rentals/<rental_pk>/contacts/<contact_pk>/`, which is kinda enforced by `rest_framework`'s `ViewSet`s.